# putting enumeration with spaces in rails collection

Tags: ruby

```
irb(main):001:0> t = %w{this is a test}
=> ["this", "is", "a", "test"]
irb(main):002:0> t.size
=> 4
irb(main):003:0> t = %w{"this is" a test}
=> ["\"this", "is\"", "a", "test"]
irb(main):004:0> t.size
=> 4
```

In the end I expected `t.size` to be 3.

As suggested, each space has to be escaped ...which turns out to be a lot of work. What other options are there? I have a list of about 30 words that I need to put in a collection because I am showing them as checkboxes using `simple_form`

Comment: What other examples do you have? Are they double quoted where you don't want to be splitted? Probably there is a better way than using `%w{}`, and in order to help you, we need to know the general pattern.

Comment: It is poor programming design to insist on using something like the `%w{}` operator, then try to fool it, when there are other, better, ways to go about it. The end result of trying to force `%w{}` to do something it's not designed to do, is cause confusion when maintaining the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use a normal array so no one has to visually parse all the escaping to figure out what's going on? This is pretty clear:

```
t = [
    'this is',
    'a',
    'test'
]
```

and the people maintaining your code won't hate you for using `%w{}` when it isn't appropriate or when they mess things up because they didn't see your escaped whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the space with a '\', like `t = %w{this\ is a test}` if you dont want that space to be a splitter.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the space using `\`:

```
%w{this\ is a test}
```

Comment: I have a load of words I am trying to get as collection. is there a better way?

Comment: Why not use an Array or a Text file instead

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the space `%w{this\ is a test}` to get `['this is', 'a', 'test']`, but in general I wouldn't use `%w` unless then intention is to split on whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out use the `%w{}` construct when spaces are the separator for the words.  If you have items that must be quoted and still want to use the construct you can do:

```
 > %w{a test here}.unshift("This is")  
 => ["This is", "a", "test", "here"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'csv'
str = '"this is" a test'
p CSV.parse_line(str,{:col_sep=>' '})
#=> ["this is", "a", "test"]
```